# Import Error: No module named pkg_resources

Tags: python-2.7, anaconda, importerror, gdal

UPDATE:

I found the cause of the problem. The first line in gdal_merge.py is

```
#!C:/Users/akg/AppData/Local/Continuum/Anaconda2\python.exe
```

The first two characters, #!, the so-called **shebang**, tells a program called Python Launcher, py.exe, what Python version to use to run the script. In my case, py.exe was registered incorrectly. (py.exe comes with Python3.3 or later and installs under C:\Windows\py.exe.)

I tested it with `> ftype Python.File`, which printed

`Python.File="C:\Python27\ArcGISx6410.3\python.exe" "%1" %*`

This causes python27 that came with ArcInfo to be used no matter what the text after the shebang says. And it is no pkg_resources in this particular Python installation, so therefore the error message.

The fix was to download and install the latest version of Python3, which also re-installs py.exe.  Now, running `> ftype Python.File` prints

```
`Python.File="C:\WINDOWS\py.exe" "%L" %*`
```

And after this, running `> gdal_merge.py` works as it should.

OLD:

I have installed Python 2.7 with **Anaconda2**, and **gdal** on a Windows 7 system.

I installed gdal with:

`> conda install -c conda-forge gdal`

When I run `gdal_merge.py` (located under the ../Anaconda2/Scripts folder) from the windows command prompt:

```
> gdal_merge.py
```

I get the error message: `ImportError: No module named pkg_resources`

In gdal_merge.py is the line:

```
__import__('pkg_resources').run_script('GDAL==2.2.0', 'gdal_merge.py')
```

that causes the import error. Python tries to import pkg_resources, but cannot find it. (I have tested to add import of other modules also, e.g. pandas, but it results in the same error.)

But pkg_resources can be imported from the Python prompt:

```
>>> import pkg_resources
>>> pkg_resources
<module 'pkg_resources' from 'C:\Users\akg\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.pyc'>
```

So why is the package not found when I run gdal_merge.py? Any fix for this?

*I tried to put ../Anaconda2/Lib/site-packages in PYTHONPATH, and that helped. This is however not ideal: when I start QGIS, this will cause it to use wrong path to import the sip module, which leads to an import error in QGIS. QGIS ships with its own Python distribution. But when PYTHONPATH points to the site-packages of Anaconda2, QGIS will try to load from it insteadof its own site-packages folder. I have also read that it should not be necessary to use PYTHONPATH for Anaconda to work.*