# Apple M1 install LLVM version 9

Tags: llvm, apple-m1, arm64, qgis, llvmlite

CONTEXT:
I am trying to install a plugin within QGIS. The plugin requires many python packages which I am installing via pip3. One of the packages being LLVMLITE at version 0.33.0. My MacOS is Ventura

I get an error saying:

```
RuntimeError: Building llvmlite requires LLVM 9.0.x, got '11.1.0'. Be sure to set LLVM_CONFIG to the right executable path.
  Read the documentation at http://llvmlite.pydata.org/ for more information about building llvmlite.
```

It is asking for LLVM version 9.

I have been successful in getting LLVM version 11 via brew. I have tried getting version 9 but I get an error:

```
llvm@9: The x86_64 architecture is required for this software.
Error: llvm@9: An unsatisfied requirement failed this build.
```

QUESTION:

Is there in anyway I can move forward?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: One way is to install everything for the x86_64 architecture, and rely on Rosetta to do the translation. That includes (or starts with) a suitable Python; and I don't know how you can actually tell Homebrew to install for x86_64 explicitly (so that it ignores the arm64 architecture).

Comment: Another option is to install LLVM from source; which may be a tedious, and perhaps near impossible, task. Or it may be very smooth, I have no experience with that.

Comment: Lastly, you could try to use a newer version of llvmlite that works with LLVM 11. That may or may not work with your plugin. But perhaps you've already tried that.

Comment: llvm-9.0 is available from [MacPorts](https://ports.macports.org/port/llvm-9.0/). It might be able to install on M1 although I haven't tried it. Note that it wants python-2.7 and thus must be really old.

Comment: Note that the Ventura part is less important here. What is more important is the Python version you are using, and the architecture (which is obviously arm64). Because you're preferably looking for Python packages that are already compiled (i.e., binary wheels) for that combination of Python & architecture.

Comment: I tried the solution from @JeremyP and it worked! I am using python3.9 and not sure what the python version differences would implicate...

Comment: @charlie090 I think the python 2.7 was a prerequisite just for building LLVM. You'll probably find that MacPorts has installed it but not as your default python.

Comment: @charlie090 if thou have answered your question, please write an answer describing what you did and then accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the advice by @JeremeyP. I could install llvm version 9 via macports. Following the install you have to change the pathing to the installation path made with macports.

Already using the QGIS tool I can see that there are implications, namely that python package versions being installed are of deprecated ones, i.e.: [Import Error: No module named pkg_resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44393017/import-error-no-module-named-pkg-resources)

You have to really need to spend sometime on the package dependencies.